# Bringing selective changes from develop to master

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using git-flow to maintain my branches, hence I have a master and develop branches.

Develop is several commits (~50-100) ahead of master.

However, there is a need to bring selective features from develop to master ahead of schedule.

How can I do this? Should be using cherry-pick? What happens if I rebase develop on master again later before the final merge back to master?

Comment: Note that in git-flow model, the `master` branch is the release branch, and should only contain merge commits from `develop`. It's a good thing to keep `master` in compliance with this model

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the advice. Except that we need to bring features into production sooner and the features are spread all over in the develop branch. I guess I have to use cherry-pick and fix/remove any changes that should not be there. Looks like the history is going to get messy during this period.

Comment: Rebasing `develop` onto `master` is not part of [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), which specifies that `develop` be non-fast-forward merged into `master`. If you collaborate on the `develop` branch with other developers, you might be causing them trouble if you rebase a shared `develop` branch, because they'll need to sync their work with the rebased branch.

Comment: We face the same issue - there's an issue with the live version which is already fixed on develop. Is it not just a case of following the hotfix process (https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/GitFlowHotfixBranch.png) but simply reverse the arrow between the red (hotfix) version and the (yellow) develop version on that diagram using a cherry-pick to grab the commit into the hotfix branch?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered creating another develop branch just for integrating these particular features, then using either `rebase -i` to remove commits you don't want, or cherry-pick the commits you do want into that branch?

It seems that you might even be able to use a git flow release branch to do this, though if you do you'd have to go with the interactive rebase/removal approach.  It's not the way release is intended, but it at least keeps master clean.

The process of removing changes at release time is documented pretty well in http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/ specifically in the section titled "Taking features out is more powerful than putting them in". You may have difficulty if your features didn't start from the same commit (which, if you follow git-flow, they probably aren't).  But you can try to make the best of it.

### Example: interactive rebase

```
$ git checkout -b reduced_functionality_branch develop
$ git rebase -i sha1-for-previous-release-point
...remove the stuff you don't want...
```

At this point, reduced_functionality_branch should contain only the commits you want to be released.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "git cherry-pick"

Please note that since you bring selective commits, commits must on source branch must be complete. You may get some merge conflicts as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cherry-pick should indeed work fine in this case. When you rebase, it will appear as though the cherry-picked changes were committed before the rest of the work, but that is what you get with a any rebase.

As CharlesB says though, cherry-picking into master is not exactly compliant with the git-flow model. But it's not far off and it is a nice simple way of resolving your particular problem.

Comment: I tried to merge the master back into develop after cherry-picking, it seems that those changes are on the top? Looks like I will have double commits since cherry-picks are new commits? And messy too in the history.

Comment: do you mean merging back into develop makes conflicts?

Comment: There were no conflicts but the new cherry-picked commits are on top because cherry-picked commits are new commits? So I'm seeing double commits in the history in develop after I merge back master to develop.

Comment: @Nora Can you post the commands you ran and the results? Otherwise it is confusing to discuss it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use .gitattributes in both dev and master branch and put below code

```
<file which is branch specific> merge=ours
```

run below command

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

and next time when you merge branches you all stuff would be merged except `<file which is branch specific>`